# React + Typescript: render prop Property * is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this setup. I made a small wrapper around `react-intl`'s injection component so I could use it as a render prop but the compiler is complaining to me...

```
interface Props {
  intl: InjectedIntl;
  children(props: InjectedIntl): JSX.Element;
}

class Intl extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  public render() {
    return this.props.children(this.props.intl);
  }
}

export default injectIntl(Intl);
```

and then the render prop is like this...

```
  <Intl> // <-- compiler complaining on this line
    {(intl) => (
      <div>
       {intl.messages.iCanHazRenderProp}
      </div>
    )}
  </Intl>
```

the compiler is complaining about the line above with this error

```
Type '{ children: (intl: InjectedIntl) => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Props, ComponentState, any>> & Readonly<...'. Type '{ children: (intl: InjectedIntl) => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Props>'. Property 'intl' is missing in type '{ children: (intl: InjectedIntl) => Element; }'.
```

EDIT: the signature of injectIntl

```
(alias) injectIntl<Props>(component: ReactIntl.ComponentConstructor<Props & ReactIntl.InjectedIntlProps>, options?: ReactIntl.InjectIntlConfig | undefined): React.ComponentClass<Props> & {
WrappedComponent: ReactIntl.ComponentConstructor<Props & ReactIntl.InjectedIntlProps>;
```

}
import injectIntl

Comment: Could you provide the source / signature of `injectIntl()`? I have a feeling that's part of the problem.

Comment: @rossipedia I added it to the post

Comment: see my submitted answer below...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the compiler to stop pooping itself when i changed the signature of `injectIntl`

`... WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<IVisualizationProps & InjectedIntlProps>`

Looks like @types/react-intl is returning a different function signature...

here's react-intl changing the function signature:

​https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/5e471f03c00b89ac358848e9cd66333466297f45​